# Correct way of showing admob before a dialog

Tags: android, admob

I received a violation from Admob for interstitial ads. I show the ad before a dialog, please snippet for the actual process flow..

[image]

Is this really a violation? If yes, I am thinking of loading the ads after a progress bar (which will simulate loading of core data, etc..). Would that work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: So like I said I am implementing a Progress bar and load the ad after that. And AdMob removed my violation. So happy it works!

Comment: wow, i am very happy after see admob remove you violation. i understand feel of developers when their app rejected/removed. Happy Coding Buddy:)  {{ if you use interstitial ad between two actvities then Best practice is- if user click on button then show Ad, if user close ad then open new activity after ad closed. i hope it related. always place ad when user take action never show ad without any action}}